# Display Most Viewed Page in SharePoint on Home Page

Tags: sharepoint

I am a beginner on SharePoint. I am trying to fetch the most viewed pages and display them on the front page in one section. Please help me how can I show Most Viewed Pages on homepage of my SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1):

We could use [Highlighted content web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd) to display most viewed page on home page:

[image]

Comment: Remeber to mark it as answer it it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Page analytics data is not accessible for filtering in a web part. You would need to code a custom web part for that.

It would also help immensely if you could detail what version of SharePoint you are working with, because the availability of tools varies wildly between online and on premises versions.